# Alinhamento de imagem responsiva com Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, bootstrap-3

Estou com dificuldade de alinhar ao centro uma imagem responsiva do Bootstrap.

Minha imagem está com a classe (`.img-responsive`) devidamente aplicada e inserida dentro de uma `row` e duma `div` com a classe `.col-md-12`.

No momento que aplico a classe `.img-responsive`, a classe `.text-center` deixa de fazer efeito e a imagem fica alinhada à esquerda.

Alguém consegue me dar uma ajuda? Desde já agradeço.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-12 text-center">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/quadro-picnic.png" alt="Imagem"/>
        </div>              
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso acontece porque a class `.img-responsive` adiciona a propriedade - `display:block;` à imagem.

Para resolver isso e fazer com que um elemento com `display:block;` seja alinhado ao centro terás que adicionar ao mesmo uma - `margin:0 auto;`, que neste caso este estilo, será implementado à class - `.img-responsive`.

No meu entender estás a utilizar a class `.text-center` não só para alinhar a imagem ao centro mas principalmente para alinhar textos, certo? Então o que podes fazer aqui é criar o código CSS da seguinte maneira:

```
.text-center .img-responsive {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Desta forma tudo o que estiver dentro da class `.text-center` será alinhado ao centro, e este estilo será apenas aplicado à class `.img-responsive` caso esta esteja dentro da class `.text-center` como é o que acontece no caso do teu código HTML, dando assim a opção de poderes usar a class `.img-responsive` livremente das duas maneiras, usá-la do modo padrão, ou centralizada adicionando a class `.text-center` como `div parent` para accionar a sua centralização.

Tens aqui um <kbd>[EXEMPLO ONLINE NO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/33a6kme4/)</kbd> do código em ação.

Comment: Perfeito Chun. É exatamente isso. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Funcionou certinho para mim, Chun. Muito obrigado!